# How to get custom field value in frontend for taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy

I have added a image filed in my custom module for taxonomy with name `custom_image` using `add_action( 'taxonomy_name_add_form_fields)`. And it successfully added and saved with taxonomy.

But how to get it on frontend in my custom template?

**EDIT :** Used this article https://gist.github.com/mathetos/1eea92f71934442671a7 Here is the code:

```
<?php

/* Add Image Upload to Series Taxonomy */

// Add Upload fields to "Add New Taxonomy" form
function add_series_image_field() {
    // this will add the custom meta field to the add new term page
    ?>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="series_image"><?php _e( 'Series Image:', 'journey' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="series_image[image]" id="series_image[image]" class="series-image" value="<?php echo $seriesimage; ?>">
        <input class="upload_image_button button" name="_add_series_image" id="_add_series_image" type="button" value="Select/Upload Image" />
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery('#_add_series_image').click(function() {
                    wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment) {
                        jQuery('.series-image').val(attachment.url);
                    }
                    wp.media.editor.open(this);
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
<?php
}
add_action( 'weekend-series_add_form_fields', 'add_series_image_field', 10, 2 );

// Add Upload fields to "Edit Taxonomy" form
function journey_series_edit_meta_field($term) {

    // put the term ID into a variable
    $t_id = $term->term_id;

    // retrieve the existing value(s) for this meta field. This returns an array
    $term_meta = get_option( "weekend-series_$t_id" ); ?>

    <tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="_series_image"><?php _e( 'Series Image', 'journey' ); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <?php
                $seriesimage = esc_attr( $term_meta['image'] ) ? esc_attr( $term_meta['image'] ) : ''; 
                ?>
            <input type="text" name="series_image[image]" id="series_image[image]" class="series-image" value="<?php echo $seriesimage; ?>">
            <input class="upload_image_button button" name="_series_image" id="_series_image" type="button" value="Select/Upload Image" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row" valign="top"></th>
        <td style="height: 150px;">
            <style>
                div.img-wrap {
                    background: url('http://placehold.it/960x300') no-repeat center; 
                    background-size:contain; 
                    max-width: 450px; 
                    max-height: 150px; 
                    width: 100%; 
                    height: 100%; 
                    overflow:hidden; 
                }
                div.img-wrap img {
                    max-width: 450px;
                }
            </style>
            <div class="img-wrap">
                <img src="<?php echo $seriesimage; ?>" id="series-img">
            </div>
            <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery('#_series_image').click(function() {
                    wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment) {
                        jQuery('#series-img').attr("src",attachment.url)
                        jQuery('.series-image').val(attachment.url)
                    }
                    wp.media.editor.open(this);
                    return false;
                });
            });
            </script>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
add_action( 'weekend-series_edit_form_fields', 'journey_series_edit_meta_field', 10, 2 );

// Save Taxonomy Image fields callback function.
function save_series_custom_meta( $term_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['series_image'] ) ) {
        $t_id = $term_id;
        $term_meta = get_option( "weekend-series_$t_id" );
        $cat_keys = array_keys( $_POST['series_image'] );
        foreach ( $cat_keys as $key ) {
            if ( isset ( $_POST['series_image'][$key] ) ) {
                $term_meta[$key] = $_POST['series_image'][$key];
            }
        }
        // Save the option array.
        update_option( "weekend-series_$t_id", $term_meta );
    }
}  
add_action( 'edited_weekend-series', 'save_series_custom_meta', 10, 2 );  
add_action( 'create_weekend-series', 'save_series_custom_meta', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to show the code that adds the fields?

Comment: Please check my edited question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to use [`update_term_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_term_meta/) and [`get_term_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/) as they were introduced in WordPress 4.4. This would help to keep your `wp_options` table smaller.

But either way, you need to know the ID of the term in the "Frontend".

Using Term meta you would need it:

`$term_meta = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'series_images', true );`

Using your solution you would need it:

`$term_meta = get_option( "weekend-series_" . $t_id );`

So the question is:

### How do I get the ID of a term?

#### How to get the current term ID on the taxonomies page

A very useful function is [`get_queried_object()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object), which returns the queried object. If you are in the taxonomy.php template, or the tag.php or the category.php this would be the current term object:

```
WP_Term Object
(
    [term_id] => 20
    [name] => Schlagwort
    [slug] => schlagwort
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 20
    [taxonomy] => post_tag
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 0
    [count] => 0
    [filter] => raw
)
```

So to get the terms ID in these templates you can do something like:

```
$current_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $current_object->term_id;
```

#### How do I get the term IDs of terms attached to a certain post?

If you want to display those images lets say in the single.php template, you would need to get the term IDs attached to the current post. With [`get_the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) you can get exactly those. If you use it inside the loop* you can simply do something like this:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'post_tag' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $term_id = $term->term_id;
    /* Do something with the $term_id */
}
```

The first parameter is the current post ID while the second parameter is the slug of the taxonomy (in my example its `post_tag` for the tags). What you get in return is an array of Term Objects.

#### How to get the term IDs of all terms of a taxonomy

At last, lets say, you have a taxonomy and you want the term IDs of all the terms attached to this taxonomy [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) is your friend.

```
$terms = get_terms( 'post_tag' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $term_id = $term->term_id;
    /* Do something with the $term_id */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, `get_option( "weekend-series_" . $t_id );` is working for me. I have already `term object` and `term id` in my custom template.